# How to return an Integer value from String using String.charAt(index);

Tags: java

Given a variable a `String number = "1234567";`
Is there a simpler way of returning the value 2 to an Integer without auto boxing and unboxing the value.
I tried `int num = number.charAt(1);` instead of returning two, it returned the Unicode index of "2".
The only option I have which are not pretty are;

```
String number = "1234567";
int numA = Integer.valueOf(number.substring(1,2));
int numB = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(number.charAt(1));
```

Comment: `Integer.parseInt()` should be used in this context, rather than `valueOf()`, as you want the primitive and not the boxed class.

Answer (score 3):

`char` is an integral type. You can just substract `'0'`, since the char values of `0`, `1`, ... , `9` are consecutive.

```
int index = 1; // or any index you like
int num = number.charAt(index) - '0';
```

Comment: Who cares? It's an index

Comment: @ribads: the index of the char in the `String` as defined in [`CharSequence`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html)

Comment: This doesn't compile.?

Comment: @pczeus: I don't know what you did to not make it compile, but this works if placed inside a class: `public static void main(String[] args) {
        String number = "1234567";
        int index = 1;
        int num = number.charAt(index) - '0';
        System.out.println(num);
    }`

Comment: You are correct, my bad. I was wrapping the code in a Groovy script, which complained because it overloads the `-`, expecting a `minus()` method. One of the rare cases that differs when executing normal Java code. But, after the failure to compile, I should have tried it in a standard Java class. My bad, this does work. Interesting too.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [Character.digit(..)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#digit%28int,%20int%29)

```
String number = "1234567";     
char at       = number.charAt(1);
int num       = Character.digit(at, 10);
```

Comment: interesting way to do it.

Comment: This looks like the cleanest way to do it.

Comment: Sweet spot!! looks clean